# Uncaught TypeError: node is null in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

i have the App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <TheQuestion></TheQuestion>
  </div>
  <br />
  <TheMenu></TheMenu>
</template>

<script>
import TheQuestion from "./components/TheQuestion.vue";
import TheMenu from "./components/TheMenu.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    TheQuestion,
    TheMenu,
  },
};
</script>
```

TheMenu.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <the-button>aaa </the-button>
    <the-button>bbb</the-button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedComponent: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setSelectedComponent(cmp) {
      this.selectedComponent = cmp;
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style></style>
```

and main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import TheButton from "./components/TheButton";
const app = createApp(App);

app.component("the-button", TheButton);
createApp(App).mount("#app");
app.mount("#app");
```

I got an error Uncaught TypeError: node is null in console and the whole App is not rendering. When i delete this component, the app is working. I wanted to use it to set dynamics component, but when i create this component, make there onyl template i style (!without script) and register in in App.vue the app is crashing. I tried registering TheMenu globally, but it didnt work.
How do i solve it? How i do deal with this type of error?

I tried registering TheMenu globally, but it didnt work.
I tried making it without JS logic- no script and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import TheButton from "./components/TheButton";
const app = createApp(App);

app.component("the-button", TheButton);
createApp(App).mount("#app");
app.mount("#app");
```

In this section you should not write the last line. Because you already mounted the app, in the after last line